# Where is ProperyLoader class?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

I attempted to follow and old tutorial for Sending E-mail with Amazon SES Using the AWS SDK for Android here:

https://developer.amazon.com/post/TxEUZC89WLEC2Z/Sending-E-mail-with-Amazon-SES-Using-the-AWS-SDK-for-Android.html

I am having a little trouble however. PropertyLoader cannot be resolved. What jar library is this a part of? I have tried importing all of the jar libraries from the SDK into my Eclipse project. (http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/).

I also get an error on this line: SendEmailResult result = clientManager.ses().sendEmail(request); I am guessing there is another class called ClientManager to set this up with in which I am also not able to find.

Any thoughts or links would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the tutorial it looks like it follows a sample. Doing a quick Google search finds me [this](https://github.com/philippb/aws-sdk-for-android/blob/master/samples/AWSAndroidDemo/src/com/amazonaws/demo/PropertyLoader.java) page.

I imagine the clientManager stuff is also there.

Note that the post is very old so I'm not even sure it still works with the current version of the SDK

Comment: I did see that file. Its more than two years old. You would think this would be apart of the of the jar library today?

Comment: @AndroidNewb I don't know too much about what this is for, but it seems like it's just there for the sample so I don't imagine it would be part of the library today

Comment: I was able to find the full sample project by AWS Labs on GitHub. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/v1/SES_FeedbackForm